# Writing and reading to and from BigQuery in one Dataflow job

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a seemingly simple problem when constructing my pipeline for Dataflow. I have multiple pipelines that fetch data from external sources, transform the data and write it to several BigQuery tables. When this process is done I would like to run a query that queries the just generated tables. Ideally I would like this to happen in the same job.

Is this the way Dataflow is meant to be used, or should the loading to BigQuery and the querying of the tables be split up between jobs?

If this is possible in the same job how would one solve this, as the BigQuerySink does not generate a PCollection? If this is not possible in the same job, is there some way to trigger a job on the completion of another job (i.e. the writing job and the querying job)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You alluded to what would need to happen to do this in a single job -- the `BigQuerySink` would need to produce a `PCollection`. Even if it is empty, you could then use it as the input to the step that reads from `BigQuery` in a way that made that step wait until the first sink was done.

You would need to create your own version of the BigQuerySink to to do this.

If possible, an easier option might be to have the second step read from the collection that you wrote to BigQuery rather than reading the table you just put into BigQuery. For example:

```
PCollection<TableRow> rows = ...;
rows.apply(BigQuery.Write.to(...));
rows.apply(/* rest of the pipeline */);
```

You could even do this earlier if you wanted to continue processing the elements written to BigQuery rather than the table rows.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Creating an implementation of the BiQuerySink is what I will do as the second answer doesn't really fit my particular case.

Comment: Hi @Supahsmooth, if an answer helped you to solve your issue also consider voting it up: https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote. It can be quite useful for those helping you :)

Comment: Hi Ben, i would like you to have a look at a question related to dataflow and bigquery [this is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50214763/unable-to-write-to-bigquery-permission-denied-apache-beam-python-google-dat) to the question. Please have a look.